# Azure VM Image with SSRS & SSIS

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis, virtual-machine, ssrs-2008-r2

I am looking for the most appropriate and cost effective Azure VM image that will allow secure access to a web application which communicates with a SSRS instance for the reporting side of the equation. I also need to be able to deploy to this VM using Web Deploy.

Note that data requirements are at the low end of the scale - I'm currently running the thing locally on my dev box - but once published it needs to accessible by people from two different domains.

In short, on the VM I'll need:

1. SQL Server
2. SSRS
3. SSIS (for uploading data in bulk)
4. IIS
5. Web Deploy
6. The ability to send email

Answer (score 6):

1, 2, and 3 are available in any SQL Server image in Azure. The rest can be installed and configured after creating the VM. The most cost effective would be to provision a SQL Server 2014 web edition VM.

Comment: Thanks for the information - very helpful :) ... I've found that Microsoft don't provide a particularly useful tool to figure out which image you might need - there doesn't seem to be any obvious **ingredients** listing